# jQuery slideDown() not animating (jquery-rails 3.0.4; jquery-ui-rails (4.0.5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following along in the latest Agile Web Development with Rails 4 book.  In Chapter 11 (AJAX), the book instructs us to use the following code in the "create.js.erb" file:

```
if ($('#cart tr').length == 1) { $('#cart').show('blind', 1000); }
```

This code causes the #cart div to jump down without any content.  After 1 second it appears.  There is no sliding effect.

I tried using slideDown(); as well, but the div just appears immediately.  Out of curiosity, I tried slideUp(); when the div was visible.  Voila.  The div slid up.

This appears to be a jQuery bug and wondered if anyone else has experienced this, or has any suggestions for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing a scenario where content is being loaded via ajax, where the toggle is not simply displaying content already present in the dom. Is that the case? Otherwise, is the content within the wrapper also hidden... perhaps with css?

Have you tried slideToggle(); for the simple dom show / hide? ... If it's ajax related, you may need to delay the toggle from firing until the content itself has loaded.

Comment: slideToggle() does work.  Content is being loaded in the DOM.  Do you think the content is loading in the DOM after the animation?

Comment: I wondered if that was the case, but if slideToggle is working then it must be available prior to that event. Don't forget to accept if all is well here.

Comment: using slideToggle() works (div is slid up or down), but .show("blind") doesn't (div immediately appears).  Any ideas why?

Comment: Using show() or hide() will do just that: show or hide your element immediately. It just applies display: block; or display: none; to the element. slideToggle() includes the animation prior to show / hiding.

Comment: .show("blind") should blind down the element.  In any case, I found the answer on the pragprog discussion forums.  Within the CSS a form div was being displayed inline.  I removed this and now the show("blind") works.  Thanks.